# Deployed EAR file does not include 'Web Service Properties' section

Tags: java, web-services, websphere-7

I had a EAR deployed to a Websphere server by our middleware group. When I look at the EAR properties in my local server console they show the *Web Service Properties* like this screenshot.  This is a web service application that works using my local server in RAD.

[image]

The screenshot from the deployed application is missing the *Web Services Properties* section. I do not have direct access to the server, this was sent to me by my middleware resource.

[image]

There is only one EAR file that was sent to be deployed. The problem of course is that the services of the deployed application are not there.  I believe that the EAR configuration is the root cause, and I am asking how to fix this issue.  I am fairly new to Websphere, and at a loss on how to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the EAR is not deployed correctly. You may have to check the logs during deployment. The logs will give you the exact reason why the EAR is not completely deployed.

Comment: I am going to hold out for a more specific answer.  I also have my doubts that this is the case, I have a very experienced resource performing the deployment.  This is large company with established processes.

Comment: That's fine. I would have written this in your comments, but I can't comment on others questions as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Also from my past experience, while deploying in websphere, if the webservice part fails, it mentions on the final step, but it can be easily missed as it does not stand out.

Comment: I understand, I remember being frustrated by the ability of not being able to comment when I was new to SO. If this turns out to be the issue, I will be sure to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed to change the project facets.Please find below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOu8G.png)

It worked for me.